# Subsetting cells in a SCE on the basis of gene expression

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am currently analysing some single cell RNA sequencing data in R using the BioConductor 'Orchestrating Single Cell Analysis with BioConductor' as a guide as I am new to this work. I have a fully analysed single cell experiment object, but would like to subset my data to produce a new single cell experiment object with only CD4+ T cells to analyse them further.

I have tried this approach:

```
sce.cd4 <- sce2[,which(assay(sce)['Cd4',] > 2000)]
```

which did not produce the desired results- when I tried to plot a tSNE of this subset the graph comes up completely blank with no cells at all. How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the output of `which(assay(sce)['Cd4',] > 2000)`? Do you have cells that fulfill that?

Comment: Also, in your code you subset `sce2` and call `which(...)` on `sce`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: The sce2/sce is a typo- I have used sce2 only in my code (sorry about that!). I don't have any cells within that sorting criteria- should I lower my threshold? I am unsure of what a good threshold to set would be

Comment: Well, you can not plot what is not there. I would recommend to explore your data. I'm not used to work with `sce` but maybe you can start with something like `summary(sce[,grep('Cd4',colnames(sce))]` to see the mean, min and max reads for Cd4 in your data and decide from there how to proceed with subsetting.